# Custom i18n routing in Symfony

Tags: symfony, internationalization, routes

I'm using `JMS\I18nRoutingBundle`, `Gedmo\Translatable` and `Gedmo\Sluggable`. Routes with default locations works as well, but other locales works without translated slug. My i18n routing have following settings:

```yml
# Doctrine extensions
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: %locale%
    translation_fallback: true
    orm:
        default:
            #…
            sluggable:      true
            translatable:   true
            loggable:       false
            #…

jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: cs_CZ
    locales: [cs_CZ, en_US]
    strategy: custom
    hosts:
        cs_CZ: example.cz
        en_US: example.com
    redirect_to_host: true
```

When I set up route like this:

```yml
hw_category:
    pattern: /category/{slug}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeSiteBundle:Category:detail }
```

```php
/**
 * @Template
 */
public function detailAction(Category $category)
{}
```

This routes works
`example.cz/category/slug-in-czech`
`example.com/category/slug-in-czech`

But I want to get work `example.com/category/slug-in-english` which throws 404 exception `object not found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, you have to override method used in entity repository:

```
/**
 * @Template
 * @ParamConverter(
 *     "category",
 *     class = "AcmeSiteBundle:Category",
 *     options = {
 *         "repository_method" = "findByTranslatedSlug"
 *     }
 *  )
 */
public function detailAction(Category $category)
{}
```

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\SiteBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CategoryRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findByTranslatedSlug($slug)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->where('c.slug = :slug')
            ->setParameters($slug);

        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        // set the translation query hint
        $query->setHint(
            \Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER,
            'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker'
        );

        return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As i see you are using the ParamConverter to automatically fetch your category.

If `slug-in-english`is an existing slug in your database but doctrine refuses to fetch it.

You probably don't have the **TranslatableListener** added to your EntityManager at that point.

**Example**:

```
$translatableListener = new \Gedmo\Translatable\TranslationListener();
$translatableListener->setTranslatableLocale('en_us');
$em->addEventSubscriber($translatableListener);
```

If you're using **StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle**:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US
    orm:
        default:
            # ...
            translatable: true
```

Comment: Where I should attach `TranslatableListener` – in which file?

Comment: are you using StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle?

Comment: Yes, I use StofDoctrineExtensionBundle and I have configured that before. ( I suppose you mean `translatable` – no `timestampable`.) Is order of extensions significant?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and as suggested by jkucharovic, you can use the **Doctrine ParamConverter** to convert your request parameters to an object

To fetch an object from the database, the Doctrine converter uses by default find() method. But since we use Translatable, therefore multiple tables, it is not enough to manage translations, that's why we need to define our own. Here comes findByTranslatedSlug.

```
/**
 * @Template
 * @ParamConverter(
 *     "category",
 *     class = "AcmeSiteBundle:Category",
 *     options = {
 *         "id" = "slug",
 *         "repository_method" = "findByTranslatedSlug"
 *     }
 *  )
 */
public function detailAction(Category $category)
{}
```

Some details about ParamConverter parameters:

- First parameter *"category"* refers to the name of the method argument (here *$category*)
- *"id"* option refers to the route placeholder you want to pass(here *{slug}*) to the customised repository method (findByTranslatedSlug()). Without setting this option, it would throw a PDO exception.

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\SiteBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CategoryRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findByTranslatedSlug($slug)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->where('c.slug = :slug')
            ->setParameter('slug',$slug);

        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        // set the translation query hint
        $query->setHint(
            \Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER,
            'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker'
        );
        // If you need to set manually the locale to en_US, you can set this query hint
        //$query->setHint(\Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener::HINT_TRANSLATABLE_LOCALE, 'en_US');

        return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

I hope this can help

Docs:

- [Doctrine ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#doctrine-converter)
- [Translatable ORM Query Hint](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md#using-orm-query-hint)

Answer (score 0):

For Symfony > 4
the work around is

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Entity;

     * @Route("/{slug}", name="your_route_name"))
     * @Entity("your_entity_name", expr="repository.findByTranslatedSlug(slug)")
```

and use the repo method from the accepted answer ;)

Searching for this the whole day, i'm glad i found your post !